# Merge [omnibar] into [address-bar]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

As far as I know [omnibar](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/omnibar)  relates either to the [Safari Omnibar](http://hackemist.com/SafariOmnibar/) or to the Google Chrome omnibar / omnibox.

As for the Safari Omnibar, it's basically a tweaked location bar (`"Search directly using location bar"`), and [location-bar](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/location-bar) is a synonym of [address-bar](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/address-bar).

As for the Google omnibar / omnibox, [even Google calls it "address bar"](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95440) so no need to refer to it as "omnibar".

22 out of the 23 questions tagged with [omnibar](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/omnibar) relate to the Google Chrome address bar, and only 1 relates to the Safari one.

Can [omnibar](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/omnibar) be merged into [address-bar](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/address-bar) and be a tag synonym of [address-bar](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/address-bar)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if even Google calls it like that, no real need to keep using "Omnibar". Note that before, Safari didn't have this, but now that it does it's no longer a unique Chrome feature.

Plus, not many questions tagged with it. If one wants to tweak the specific behavior of a browser's address bar, they'll use the proper tag for the browser as well.

I've synonymized them and merged them.